# Not getting invite mail from Grafana

Tags: email, smtp, grafana, sendgrid, dashboard

I'm trying to enable email notification in grafana using sendgrid.

However I'm getting the below error in logs after sending invite from grafana UI.

- lvl=eror msg="Async sent email 0 succeed, not send emails:
  *****@gmail.com err: Failed to send notification to email addresses: *****@gmail.com: 535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password" logger=notifications

Please see below my grafana configuration:

```
[smtp]
enabled = true
host = smtp.sendgrid.net:587
user = *****@****.in
# If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with triple quotes. Ex """#password;"""
password = ***********
;cert_file =
;key_file =
;skip_verify = false
from_address = *****@****.in
from_name = Grafana
# EHLO identity in SMTP dialog (defaults to instance_name)
;ehlo_identity = dashboard.example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I can see that your username is an email address, so I think your credentials are wrong.

When setting [SMTP credentials to send with SendGrid](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/integrating-with-the-smtp-api) the username should be the exact string `apikey` and the password should be an API key with at least "Mail" permissions.